# Magento extension access product by user

Tags: magento, admin

I need an extension, product management by user in admin for magento. I was looking for a long time on the magento connect but can not find.

Comment: I would suggest this as off topic if I weren't convinced that this is going to require programming to get done.

Answer (score 1):

Doing product management in the backend requires an admin account, and admin permissions. Users do not have these permissions, and even creating an account for them seems like a fantastically bad idea. Furthermore, technically speaking, I cannot *imagine* a clean solution for accomplishing this in a way that could be packaged.

With more detail on what you actually need to do, I'm sure that we can help suggest some paths to get this done, but I am not aware of any packaged extension that would do it for you.